# How to POST ajax call using .netcore 2.0 with data response

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to make an ajax call in .netcore 2.0. After doing some research online I have added the cshtml and the method below to my project.  The current state of my application is that when I click the `CreateNewTwitterData` input "Hello world" is return as my new page (I have not written an java script as yet but this functionality was carried out is it the CSHTML that makes the post request?). I would like to keep the same page with the URL below and using some java-script to update the information on the current page.

Current URL:
http://localhost:5808/Manifest/Details?id=80004

CSHTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="image" data-id="@Model.ManifestViewModel.ID" asp-page-handler="CreateTwitterItem" src="~/images/twitterlogo.jpg" name="New Twitter" id="CreateNewTwitterData" />
</form>
```

C#:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCreateTwitterItemAsync(long? id)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    return new JsonResult("Hello world");
}
```

I have tried the ajax method below but the code does not reach the success point.

```
$('#CreateNewTwitterData').click(function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Manifest/Details?id=' + $(CreateNewTwitterData).data("id") + '&handler=CreateTwitterItem', // <-- Where should this point?
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    })
})
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Rob no error I am getting the "Hello World" as a new page instead of the same page and alert output should display "Hello World"

Comment: You'd somehow have to actually bind an event handler to the form's `submit` event to actually call that AJAX, which you may have done but the code for that is not here. However, without that, then of course your AJAX isn't working.

Comment: ... and sweet merciful God, the more I see of Razor Pages, the more my skin crawls. Microsoft needs to drug test the development team. Whatever logic went into deciding to resurrect Web Forms, must have been drug-induced.

Comment: @ChrisPratt `[BindProperty]` is on my object which is used to populate the view. If I update this object will the view update without refreshing the page? Do you have a link to any useful tutorial or example using ajax with data response in .netcore 2.0

Comment: When I hit refresh on the browser the alert work as expected.

Comment: I do not understand how you want this to work. Is there a button that when you click a post should be issued? Do you want this post when the page loads? Does it have to be post or can a get work too? There are so many things here that don't add up. For instance. You are issuing a post with route /Manifest/Details/?id=x but your action doesn't have a [HttpPost] attribute nor does it have the same name as the action you are requesting. Details != OnPostCreateTwitterItemAsync.

Comment: @Rob I have a button which I click and it will create a new object on the same page. I do not want the page to be refreshed. The button is on this page `http://localhost:5808/Manifest/Details?id=80004`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an Ajax solution using.Netcore 2.0 razor page after trial and error but I am not sure if it is the best solution It worked for me so I thought I would share it.(In addition, I realised I didn't need the `form` tags in the cshtml with `asp-page-handler` this was making its own call ).

CSHTML:

```
<img type="image" class="socialmediaicon" data-id="@Model.ManifestViewModel.ID" src="~/images/twitterlogo.jpg" name="New Twitter" id="CreateNewTwitterData" asp-route-id="@Model.ManifestViewModel.ID" height="20" width="20" />
```

AJAX:

```
$('#CreateNewTwitterData').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Manifest/Details?id=" + $(CreateNewTwitterData).data("id") + "&handler=CreateTwitterItem", // <-- Where should this point?
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        dataType: "json", success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    })
})
```